# Is there a need to update the firmware in "Ethernet Unmanaged Switch"?

Tags: ethernet, netgear-switch

I use "GS105 — 5 Port Gigabit Ethernet Unmanaged Switch" since many years. Do I need to update the firmware? I found nothing on [Support / GS105](https://www.netgear.com/support/product/gs105#ConfigurationAssistance_CommonTopics)

How-To update the firmware?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to update the firmware?

In most cases, no. Since the switch is unmanaged, its firmware *doesn't have* much that would be worth updating – just the bare minimum necessary to initialize the dedicated Ethernet switch chip that Netgear probably bought from Realtek, with all its packet-switching functionality already hardwired.

> How-To update the firmware?

Most "unmanaged" switches have no management interface, network-based or otherwise *(hence the name "unmanaged")*, meaning there's no way to connect to them for firmware update.

<sub>(Well, TP-Link's "Unmanaged Pro" is an exception to that; the popular TL-SG10xE do have their own firmware with a web management interface. That's not the case for Netgear GS105 though.)</sub>